# Android InApp Purchase: getPurchases returns empty response

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, billing, android-billing

I have an app which contains 4 `Managed` In App Purchases and using In App Billing API v3. The purchases works fine. In order for restoring the purchases, when I make a call to `getPurchases(...)` it doesn't show any owned SKUs.

Following is the code snippet:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
alert("response " + response);
ArrayList ownedSkus = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
ArrayList purchaseDataList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
ArrayList signatureList = ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
String continuationToken = ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

alert("ownedSkus " + ownedSkus);
for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
    String purchaseData = (String) purchaseDataList.get(i);
    String signature = (String) signatureList.get(i);
    String sku = (String) ownedSkus.get(i);

    alert("PURACHSED ITEM " + i + " === " + sku);

    // do something with this purchase information
    // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
}
```

Has anybody experienced anything similar? Am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I am having this same problem. The service response OK, both INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST and INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST are empty. But if I try to purchase one product it give me a error "You already own this item".

Comment: I posted my answer, please have a look.

Comment: In my case I am using consumables and got empty purchases and "already own" message....  Whatever, thanks for reply, at least, you fill a answer :P

Comment: @Sisso - I'm facing the exact same problem: Consumable, the lists are empty but it gives me the error "You already own this item" - did you solve this?

Comment: @Sisso and @swalkner - did you guys go through my answer? I posted the solution. Are you calling the `consume` method?

Comment: @Mahendra - In my case I called consume. When I list my purchases (not consumed yet) it was empty, when try to purchase it return error "already own". I didn't understand what happens, but I think that was related with the google play test environment, cache or some bug in my library. The problem simple disappear.

Comment: @Sisso I'm facing the exact same problem now. Did you do anything to solve it or it just disappeared?

Comment: @pkacprzak - Take a look in my previous comment. Yes its simply disappears. Probably some cache or the google test environment.

Comment: Have you get RESPONSE_INAPP_SIGNATURE_LIST in Ownsku when go thrrough to refresh inventry in response of getPurchases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code which my client gave me was written by a previous developer. After referring to the docs and checking the source code I identified the cause for this.

The docs says:

> If you are using the Version 3 API, you can also consume managed items within your application. You would typically implement consumption for items that can be purchased multiple times (such as in-game currency, fuel, or magic spells). Once purchased, a managed item cannot be purchased again until you consume the item, by sending a consumption request to Google Play.

The previous developer was actually `consuming` the purchase which makes it available again for purchase. Since my InApp Purchase was `Managed` there was no need to call `consume`.

After I removed the call to `consume the product` everything worked fine.

Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#managed) from the docs.